# TinyMCE Editor text is not showing while using it in Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE Editor Extender and trying to show the text on clicking on datalist(its in other update panel) Item Template button click, I am using textbox and extender inside update panel when I am selecting an item, text is getting lost when page is loading its working fine I am able to see the text as I am selecting the item text is getting disable. I am using mode:exact, I can't change it into textarea.

I tried with http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=6034 but its working only for textarea.

how to make it working with exact mode. Someone please give some solution.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
     <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txb1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <ext:TinyMceExtender runat="server" ID="TinyMceExtender1" TargetControlID="txb1"Theme="FullWithImage"></ext:TinyMceExtender>
      </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

when i'm using only..

```
   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(UpdatePanel1, this.GetType(), "init", "tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, '" + txb1.ClientID + "');", true);
```

then text is not getting lost but next item text is not showing, and when i am adding updatepanel1.update(); with it then again onload(for the first time), text is showing but as I am clicking on datalist item text is lost.

Plz someone help me..

Comment: if you use the exact mode you will need to specifiy ids of the elements which should be turned into an editor instance

Comment: plz someone help me in this... I am stuck here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using tinyMCE editor on same page, removed the extender and added

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function () {
    TinyMCEEditor();
});
```